# How to have an environment variable with quotes in crontab

Tags: unix, cron

I have a minimum example of my problem, which is trying to install a crontab that looks like this:

```
FOO="foo\"bar\"bin"

0 0 1 * * ls
```

by running `crontab crontab` (I have it in a file name `crontab`). It fails with this error:

```
% crontab crontab
"crontab":0: bad minute
crontab: errors in crontab file, can't install
```

It's the escaped quote, `\"`, causing the problem.

How do I escape quotes in crontab's environment variables?

I'm not asking how to add environment variables to a shell script. I know how to do that. If you want to know why my question is different, here's the context: I'm not just writing variables in a manually written crontab. This crontab is generated by [whenever][1] (a Ruby gem), it has about 70 entries in them, and it picks up all environment variables and puts them as variables in the crontab so all credentials are available to the scripts. The problem is that recently I added a complex one that has quotes in it, and that broke this system.

In case you are curious, the Ruby code that generates the variables is:

```rb
ENV.each do |key, value|
  env key.to_sym, value.inspect
end
```

Comment: Can you explain in your question why you need this? Variables in `crontab` are limited. Why don't you call a shell script from your `crontab` and set the variables inside the script?

Comment: @Bodo: that is long and complicated. The crontab is generated by whenever, with about 70 entries in them, which are ruby scripts that need credentials from the environment variables. All envvars are converted into crontab variables automatically in the script that generates it. I recently added an environment variable that has quotes inside which broke the generated crontabs. So I'm trying to fix that.

Comment: I don't know if it is possible to escape quotes in `crontab`. That's why I suggest to put the variables in a script instead. Or maybe split the variable that currently needs embedded quotes into separate variables and combine these and add the quotes in your ruby script.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is crossposted: https://serverfault.com/questions/1142663/how-to-have-an-environment-variable-with-quotes-in-crontab

Comment: @RomeoNinov: that's ironic, I posted in serverfault when I noticed the first voting to close it, without any comments or messages of any kind. My experience is that someone votes to close and then people just follow without any comments.

Comment: @Bodo it's not possible to put the variables in a script. The variables are put into the crontab the crantab by whenever picking them up from the environment. It's not just a script, its 60 or so different ruby programs that need to run with all those environment variables present (the server configuration).

Comment: @PabloFernandez, As you can see in ServerFault close votes are clean. And there you have two answers (which can be IMHO helpful)

Comment: @PabloFernandez, if you add a bit of logic in shell script you can get these different environments for ruby.

Comment: @RomeoNinov I'm not sure what you are proposing with shell scripts.

Comment: @PabloFernandez, I added script and some explanations in https://serverfault.com/questions/1142663/how-to-have-an-environment-variable-with-quotes-in-crontab

Comment: @PabloFernandez I don't understand why you insist that it is not possible to use a script. I don't have any experience with ruby, but there might be a way to use a single file to define the variables and use/source this file in all scripts. You could implement a single shell script linked to 60 different names that sets the variables and runs a ruby script with a name derived from the called script name `$0`, e.g. a script run as `foo-wrapper` will set the variables and run `foo` by simply removing the trailing `-wrapper` part. The links could easily be auto-generated for all ruby scripts.

Comment: @Bodo: there are two aspects. One is that I am just trying to solve the problem that I caused by adding an envvar with a quote, not change our whole crontab. But second, let's say I have a shell script that runs 60s ruby scripts or 60 shell scripts (all these cases are actually quite cumbersome to maintain). Where would that shell script get the values for the variables from? These are secrets that exists on the server at the time `whenever` is run, and get injected in the crontab. If that doesn't happen, those shell script can't have access to those secrets.

Comment: @Bodo and yes, we can change how secrets are handled and not put them in environment variables. But that's not a quick solution. Actually, all of this is moot by now since we couldn't cope with a broken crontab anymore and we found some workarounds.

Comment: @PabloFernandez The fact that you now reached limitations of crontab files could be the result of a bad design. If you cannot solve this in crontab you can either avoid using quotes or use a different way to provide the variables. The script could write the variables to a different file that is somehow read or executed by all your crontab entries. It could be a shell script containing only variable assignments that is sourced by other scripts or it could contain other code in addition to the variables. Or all your ruby scripts might read the file. Without details I cannot write a real answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I could find, crontab variables just cannot have quotes and they also can't be more than 999 characters long. The answer to this question is that it's simply not possible.